# Lamp in Ubuntu 16.04 and .htaccess file - not work

Tags: apache2, lamp, .htaccess

I installed on Ubuntu 16.04 LAMP from this tutorial: [How To Install WordPress with LAMP on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-lamp-on-ubuntu-16-04).

When I installed only Wordpress on this LAMP everything works correctly. But when I copied my page on Wordpress, Apache returned error 500:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
> unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to
> inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
> performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
> log.
>
> Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.10.120 Port 80

I think this may be a problem with the file `.htaccess`:

```
# Apache config 
<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff)">   
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" 
</FilesMatch>

# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteBase / 
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# php_value max_execution_time 300
```

Because in clean installed `Wordpress`, `.htaccess` is empty and then everything works correctly.
Do I have to install something else in order for the page to work ?

This is `error.log` from `var/log/apach2/error.log`

```
[Mon Mar 27 09:08:47.663417 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 15538]
AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal ope$
[Mon Mar 27 09:08:47.663501 2017] [core:notice] [pid 15538] AH00094:
Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2' [Mon Mar 27 09:16:04.982425 2017]
[core:alert] [pid 16677] [client 192.168.10.46:53100]
/var/www/html/kopiapbs/.htaccess: Invalid co$ [Mon Mar 27
09:22:29.850458 2017] [core:alert] [pid 16459] [client
192.168.10.46:53184] /var/www/html/kopiapbs/.htaccess: Invalid co$ [Mon Mar 27 09:23:04.754081 2017] [core:alert] [pid 16459] [client
192.168.10.46:53200] /var/www/html/kopiapbs/.htaccess: Invalid co$ [Mon Mar 27 09:23:15.646759 2017] [core:alert] [pid 16458] [client
192.168.10.46:53205] /var/www/html/kopiapbs/.htaccess: Invalid co$ [Mon Mar 27 09:26:03.453740 2017] [core:alert] [pid 16661] [client
192.168.10.120:60456] /var/www/html/kopiapbs/.htaccess: Invalid c$ [Mon Mar 27 09:26:06.668605 2017] [core:alert] [pid 16662] [client
192.168.10.120:60458] /var/www/html/kopiapbs/.htaccess: Invalid c$ [Mon Mar 27 09:26:07.253867 2017] [core:alert] [pid 16660] [client
192.168.10.120:60460] /var/www/html/kopiapbs/.htaccess: Invalid c$ [Mon Mar 27 09:26:07.731521 2017] [core:alert] [pid 16679] [client
192.168.10.120:60462] /var/www/html/kopiapbs/.htaccess: Invalid c$ [Mon Mar 27 09:26:08.221063 2017] [core:alert] [pid 16457] [client
192.168.10.120:60464] /var/www/html/kopiapbs/.htaccess: Invalid c$ [Mon Mar 27 09:26:08.689843 2017] [core:alert] [pid 16680] [client
192.168.10.120:60466] /var/www/html/kopiapbs/.htaccess: Invalid c$ [Mon Mar 27 09:26:09.100912 2017] [core:alert] [pid 16677] [client
192.168.10.120:60468] /var/www/html/kopiapbs/.htaccess: Invalid c$ [Mon Mar 27 09:26:13.998190 2017] [core:alert] [pid 17860] [client
192.168.10.120:60470] /var/www/html/kopiapbs/.htaccess: Invalid c$
```

Comment: First not an expert but I think this `".(eot|ttf|otf|woff)"` should be `"\.(eot|ttf|otf|woff)"` since your trying to match files ending with those extensions

Comment: Please try this in the terminal `a2enmod headers`

Comment: @George I use `a2enmod headers` and I restarted apache, still not work

Comment: @George When I use `a2enmod headers` I have white page.